# How to Translate Python GUI app using babel?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, babeljs, translation

I would be really grateful for your help:

i'm trying to localize my GUI app, let's say to belarussian lang. I've already extracted a label string and compiled a .mo file. For the first try i just want to open the app with the mentioned string translated by default, once the app loaded. However seems the translation is skipped for some reason.
Could you please help me to find where the mistake is?:

messages.mo directory : C:\Users\MyUser\PycharmProjects\PersFin\translations\be\LC_MESSAGES

label string i want to translate:

```
my_transactions_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text=_("**My Transactions**"),
    font=('Helvetica', 12, 'bold'), fg='dodger blue')
```

translation code(beginning block before the main program part) :

```
translations = Translations.load(r'C:\Users\MyUser\PycharmProjects\PersFin\translations\be\LC_MESSAGES', locales=[Locale('be')])
os.environ['LANG'] = 'be'
translations.install()
```

**This is what .po file contains(.mo file compiled from):**

```
# Belarusian translations for PROJECT.
# Copyright (C) 2023 ORGANIZATION
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PROJECT project.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, 2023.
#
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PROJECT VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: EMAIL@ADDRESS\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2023-08-30 22:36+0300\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2023-08-30 22:40+0300\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language: be\n"
"Language-Team: be <LL@li.org>\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=3; plural=(n%10==1 && n%100!=11 ? 0 : n%10>=2 && "
"n%10<=4 && (n%100<10 || n%100>=20) ? 1 : 2)\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Generated-By: Babel 2.9.1\n"

#: PersFin_5.0.py:572
msgid "My Transactions"
msgstr "Мае Транзакцыі"
```

I tried:re-compile the .mo file, restart IDE, check the destinations/directories, gettext...

Comment: Make sure the .mo file is generated correctly. You can use the following command to compile the .po file into a .mo file: `pybabel compile -d translations -l be -i translations/be/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po`. Double-check the path to the .mo file. Make sure the path is correct and the file is present in the directory. Instead of using `os.environ['LANG'] = 'be'`, you can try setting the locale explicitly using `locale.setlocale()`. If you are still facing issues, try to print the translated string before creating the LabelFrame. This would help debug if the translation is being fetched correctly.

Comment: Hi! Thanks you much, i've done it in the following way(for german now, i though that it might be not working for belarussian only), but it still not working: 
language_code = "de"
mo_file_path = r"C:\Users\MyUser\PycharmProjects\PersFin\translations\de\LC_MESSAGES\messages.mo"
translations = gettext.translation('messages', mo_file_path, languages=[language_code])
translations.install()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de') It says "No translations found for domain 'messages'

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you have included `be\LC_MESSAGES` in the path you passed to `Translations.load`. The path should end at the top of the translations directory, where it would find the different language subdirectories, so that the specified locale can be used to pick which subdirectory to use.